# Access filter data

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

how to write a vba code for filter data in access form where table column is NULL and another table column is equal to Combobox

I want to display record in form only if column1 is Null and  column2 is equal to combobox

```
Private Sub Command94_Click()
If Me.Check85 = True And Me.Check87 = False Then
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "[Column2]=" & "'" & [Combo59] & "'"
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , strWhereCondition
```

Comment: please, improve the 'quality' of your question for better understanding...

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway there:

```
strWhereCondition = " [Column1] Is NULL And [Column2] = '" & [Combo61] & "' "
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , strWhereCondition
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not working. Still it display all the values equal to combo box but not null

Comment: What do you mean "but not null"? You want the values that have either column1 null or column2 equal to your combo? Or the ones that have both column1 null AND column2 equal to the combo?